# Gesture control error :AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'convexityDefects'

Tags: python, debugging, opencv, gesture-recognition

I was trying out [this tutorial](http://anikettatipamula.blogspot.in/2012/02/hand-gesture-using-opencv.html) for gesture recognition and control

It was working well until I added this part to the code :

```
defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt,hull)

mind=0
maxd=0

for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
    s,e,f,d = defects[i,0]
    start = tuple(cnt[s][0])
    end = tuple(cnt[e][0])
    far = tuple(cnt[f][0])
    dist = cv2.pointPolygonTest(cnt,centr,True)
    cv2.line(img,start,end,[0,255,0],2)
    cv2.circle(img,far,5,[0,0,255],-1)

print(i)
i=0
```

For some reason python is showing this error for the `convexityDefects` function.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "F:\Python programs\python ocv\gesture detect.py", line 37, in  
<module> defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt,hull) AttributeError:  
'module' object has no attribute 'convexityDefects'
```

I have the latest version of numpy, scipy and cv2 installed. If I comment out just this portion of the code it all runs fine.

Comment: weird. 2.4.8 and 3.0.0 seem to have it here.

Comment: yeah. its there in the documentation as well. some problem with installation probably? i tried checking the modules with 
dir(cv2)
couldnt find it there either..
guess re installing it should do. I'll do that and post.

Comment: reinstalled cv. this time 2.4.9
Still not working. And again i couldnt find it in the directory

Comment: its alright :)I got cv.ConvexityDefects working..
That should do.
thanks :)

Comment: hhmm, not convinced. the old cv module is deprecated, no more available in 3.0;  and careful - it's using different datastructures than the cv2 one.

Comment: yeah.i am not able to simply replace it. This cannot be an alternative. Still searching for a soln. I'll try installing 2.4.2.. That should have it.